# Guessing a word in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a guessing game with an additional line: You have "x" guesses left.

I basically wrote these codes :

```
correctanswer = "Stackoverflow"
useranswer = ""
guesscount= -2
guesslimit = 4
outofguesses = False
while useranswer != correctanswer and not outofguesses == True:
    if guesscount <= guesslimit:
        useranswer = input("Enter your answer : ")
        guesscount += 1
        guesslimit -= 1
        print("Wrong answer , you have " + str(guesslimit) + " guess rights left")
    else: outofguesses = True

if outofguesses:
    print("You lost , sorry")
else:
    print("You won!")
```

But what I can't make it, that when the answer is correct, it still says :
("Wrong answer , you have " + str(guesslimit) + " guess rights left") and then "You won!"

What I want to do is, when given the correct answer I don't want that line to appear. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your print line is in the while loop after guessing and before checking if it is true, which means it will still execute.
One way to fix this is by using a simple if statement. Your code could look something like this
(note that the guesslimit and guesscount will still be changed, if you dont want this simply put the if statement above the code that changes them).

```
correctanswer = "Stackoverflow"
useranswer = ""
guesscount= -2
guesslimit = 4
outofguesses = False
while useranswer != correctanswer and not outofguesses == True:
    if guesscount <= guesslimit:
        useranswer = input("Enter your answer : ")
        guesscount += 1
        guesslimit -= 1
        if (useranswer != correctanswer):
            print("Wrong answer , you have " + str(guesslimit) + " guess rights left")
    else: outofguesses = True

if outofguesses:
    print("You lost , sorry")
else:
    print("You won!")
```

Answer (score 3):

Aside from doing some weird stuff with guesslimit, you are always printing "wrong answer" directly after the user answers, without performing any check to see if it's correct.

```py
correctanswer = "Stackoverflow"
guesscount = 0
guesslimit = 3
user_won = False
while guesscount < guesslimit:
    answer = input("Enter your answer : ")
    if answer == correctanswer:
        user_won = True
        break
    else:
        print(f"Wrong answer, you have {guesslimit - guesscount} guesses left")
        guesscount += 1

if user_won:
    print("You won!")
else:
    print("You lost , sorry")
```

Comment: Well thank you. I discovered that weird stuff myself as I'm a really really beginner.